# PATH variable set for MySQL, but command line doesn't work unless in bin directory

Tags: mysql, windows

I just set up MySQL and am trying to access the command line client (monitor, not shell) to be able to follow the tutorials at MySQL.com

I ensured that the PATH environment variable included the appropriate directory where mysql.exe exists:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`

This should mean that I can call `mysql` or `mysql.exe` from any directory to start up the command line interface, right? Or am I missing something?

I can still only open the monitor via command line from the above directory. Then everything works fine.

**edit:** Barmar suggested that this might be the wrong path. I am unsure of the difference between "client" and "server" in the context of MySQL. I thought I was installing a MySQL server onto my computer to learn to manage databases. I guess that's a whole different can of worms.

Comment: That's the server directory, there might be a different directory for the client.

Comment: @Barmar cool, Thanks! In my MySQL program files, I only have the options of router, server, shell and workbench... Maybe it's workbench? I just started today, so I don't know the difference between client and server yet.